# doAfterTerminate happening before Flux completes

Tags: java, kotlin, project-reactor

I am trying to understand how `doAfterTerminate` works with `delaySequence`. I have the following test:

```java
@Test
fun testDoAfterTerminate() {
    logger.info("Starting test")
    val sch = Schedulers.single()
    val testFlux = Flux.fromArray(intArrayOf(1, 2, 3).toTypedArray())
        .doAfterTerminate { logger.info("Finished processing batch!") }
        .delaySequence(Duration.ofSeconds(1), sch)
        .doOnNext { logger.info("Done $it")}
        .doAfterTerminate { logger.info("Finished v2")}
    StepVerifier.create(testFlux).expectNextCount(3).verifyComplete()
}
```

The output of this test is:

```
22:27:54.547 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Finished processing batch!
22:27:55.561 [single-1] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 1
22:27:55.561 [single-1] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 2
22:27:55.561 [single-1] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 3
22:27:55.562 [single-1] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Finished v2
```

Does anyone understand why the first `doAfterTerminate` is called before the flux completes?

If I remove the `.delaySequence(Duration.ofSeconds(1), sch)` line, the termination happens as expected:

```
22:29:37.588 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 1
22:29:37.588 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 2
22:29:37.588 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Done 3
22:29:37.588 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Finished v2
22:29:37.588 [Test worker] INFO leon.patmore.kafkareactive.TestReactor - Finished processing batch!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first `doAfterTerminate` is triggered on the main thread without any delay. Later, the signals are delayed and continue on the `single()` Scheduler.

Adding some `logs()` to make it more clear:

```
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxPeekFuseable.PeekFuseableSubscriber)
INFO main r.Flux.Peek.2 - onSubscribe(FluxPeek.PeekSubscriber)
INFO main r.Flux.Peek.2 - request(unbounded)
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | request(unbounded)
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | onNext(1)
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | onNext(2)
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | onNext(3)
INFO main r.F.P.1 - | onComplete()
Finished processing batch!
Done 1
Done 2
INFO single-1 r.Flux.Peek.2 - onNext(1)
Done 3
INFO single-1 r.Flux.Peek.2 - onNext(2)
INFO single-1 r.Flux.Peek.2 - onNext(3)
INFO single-1 r.Flux.Peek.2 - onComplete()
Finished v2
```